# Using alias for joining multiple tables in peewee

Tags: python-3.7, peewee

I have one entries table on which I have to loop over 40k records and show their data in table. As that table is related to three foreign key data, I tried to add those data in the base query itself to reduce extra queries.

I think my base query containing something like `<Model: Customer>` which is causing the issue.

lets say this are my classes

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database


class Customer(BaseModel):
    name = TextField()


class Farmer(BaseModel):
    name = TextField(null=False)


class Product(BaseModel):
    name = TextField()


class Entries(BaseModel):
    farmer = ForeignKeyField(Farmer, backref='entries')
    customer = ForeignKeyField(Customer, backref='entries')
    product = ForeignKeyField(Product, backref='product')
    other = TextField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'entries'
```

The query I tried

```
entries = Entries.select(
    Entries,
    Farmer.name.alias('farmer_name'),
    Customer.name.alias('customer_name'),
    Product.name.alias('product_name')
).join(Farmer, Customer, Product)
```

It generates the sql

```
SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."farmer_id", "t1"."customer_id", "t1"."product_id", "t1"."other", "t2"."name" AS "farmer_name", "t3"."name" AS "customer_name", "t4"."name" AS "product_name" FROM "entries" AS "t1" <Model: Customer> "farmer" AS "t2" ON "product" AS "t4"
```

I also tried seperate joins using switch method but no success.

Is it possible to fetch the data within same instance or I have to do seperate queries only?

## update

When I do the following query with `dicts()`, it works fine, but without it, it shows `AttributeError: 'Entries' object has no attribute 'farmer_name'`.

Query:

```
entries = Entries.select(
    Entries,
    Farmer.name.alias('farmer_name'),
    Customer.name.alias('customer_name'),
    Product.name.alias('product_name')
).join(Farmer, on=(Entries.farmer == Farmer.id)) \
    .join(Customer, on=(Entries.customer == Customer.id)) \
    .join(Product, on=(Entries.product == Product.id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peewee, by default, will put those aliases on the actual joined model, e.g.

```
entries = (Entries
  .select(
    Entries,
    Farmer.name.alias('farmer_name'),
    Customer.name.alias('customer_name'),
    Product.name.alias('product_name'))
  .join_from(Entry, Farmer)
  .join_from(Entry, Customer)
  .join_from(Entry, Product))
for e in entries:
    print(e.farmer.farmer_name, e.customer.customer_name)  # etc
```

If you just want everything on the entry, then add ".objects()" which prevents the graph generation and slaps everything on "Entry":

```
for e in entries.objects():  # Added .objects()
    print(e.farmer_name, e.customer_name)  # etc
```

Doc: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#selecting-from-multiple-sources

Comment: Thanks @coleifer, it worked. just curious, when we are using `e.farmer.farmer_name`, will it make a new query for it?

Comment: No, that's the whole idea -- the docs will also explain this. If you wish to verify you can turn on query debug logging or disable lazy-loading of foreign-keys. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html?highlight=logging.debug#logging-queries